# How important is it to be W3C complaint?

Tags: seo, wordpress, page-speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML validation: is it worth it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/310/html-validation-is-it-worth-it)

How important is to be W3C complaint. Currently I have 27 errors reported by W3C validator. Is that ok or I need to reduce the error count?

Comment: If you use the site search the answer to all of these questions are already here. If you have a specific problem we can help but we are not a service for checking you have built your site correctly.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Given the downvotes, i'd delete the question and start again.

Answer (score 2):

Your website may have errors, but it really depends upon the *type* of error.

- Are they broken links? If they are, you should fix them as they may negatively impact your search engine ranking.
- Are they 404 errors because of missing CSS/Javascript? These can cause HTTPS connections to show as unsafe in some browsers like Chrome, worrying your users that their sensitive data is at jeopardy.
- Are they DOCTYPE errors? The wrong DOCTYPE on your HTML can cause your website to render improperly in some browsers.
- Are they general HTML/CSS errors? These can cause your website to display improperly as well as slow down the display of your website, as the browser may have to take extra time to figure out how to display the broken code.

Sometimes there are errors you just can't fix because they are out of your control. Ultimately, your goal would be to have no errors. It's not mission critical that you fix all the errors, but for an optimal user experience a no error site helps.